# Integrate first derivation - area under curve of first derivation

Tags: r, integral, numerical-integration, curves

I want to calculate the area under the first derivate. Can I do that with splinefun()?

```
Year <- c(1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969)
Population <- c(4835, 4970, 5085, 5160, 5310, 5260, 5235, 5255, 5235, 5210, 5175)
sample <- data.frame(Year, Population)
sample
plot(sample, type='l')
spline <- splinefun(sample$Year, sample$Population)
plot(sample$Year, spline(sample$Year, deriv=1), type='l', axes=T)
```

Or is there another way to calculate the area under the first derivate?

Comment: The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus says that areas under the first derivative of a function are given by differences of values of that function itself, so there's not much more to say. What is the statistical motivation behind this question? What is your calculation attempting to represent?